# Google Analytics seeming impossible results

Tags: google-analytics

I'm a Google Analytics newbie using it to satisfy my curiosity as to where my very-low-traffic website is being looked at from and what pages they're looking at. Frequently I see results that seem impossible given my understanding of what I think I'm looking at. What I do each morning is check to see from which cities it has been viewed, then look at which pages have been looked at from each city. This morning's results illustrate the supposed problem. The website was looked at from Eugene, Oregon and from Vienna, Austria. Both showed the exact same pages looked at for the exact same amount of time. That this should happen without their usage being linked would seem impossible. Somehow it has to be the same usage, but I can't figure out how they would be linked. Can anyone enlighten me? I Googled for awhile trying to find the answe but without success.

Comment: @EduardoCereto While anything can happen in the realm of probabilities, when the same thing happens at least once a week if not more, and the cities involved are different and in different countries, and there's always at least 3 pages involved, and the times are the same, I can't believe it's a coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you site is likely being visited by automated scripts running out of those 2 cities(or by proxy).  THey are likely spammer scripts or scripts designed to find vulnerabilities in your sites security.

Comment: Would this, though, produce the same amount of time spent on each page? For example, this morning it showed:

main page 22 minutes    0 bounce   0 exit
2nd page   0 minutes    0 bounce 100 exit
3rd page   0 minutes  100 bounce 100 exit

Comment: well its possible if the same script was ran theoretically it should take about the same time to execute the same activities.  I'm not saying that this is one hundred percent correct but when I hear to locations that far apart exhibiting the same behavior I generally suspect automation.